# login password required to access jupyter notebook running in nvidia-docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-16.04

I run this command in the following order in order to run tensoflow in docker container after successful installation  in Ubuntu 16.04 (NVIDIA GPU GeFORCE 840M) .

1.sudo service docker start 
2.sudo nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

Then I try to access jupyter in firefox browser by typing localhost:8888 and I am asked to enter the login password in the browser.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add option "-e PASSWORD=password" to set the environment variable. The set password is then the password for the jupyter login.

Comment: Thanks  you very much