# Jupyter password and Docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

For changing / setting the password of a Jupyter server, I follow the instructions here:

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#preparing-a-hashed-password

I do this in my local ipython environment. One thing to note is that somehow I get different hashes every time I re-run the `passwd()` command for the same password, but I assume that's intended behavior.

Anyway. I get the hash, and then I have a line like this in a Dockerfile:

`ENV PW_HASH="u'sha1:salt:hash'"`

and in the start-up script for the jupyter notebook I have

`echo "c.NotebookApp.password = ${PW_HASH}" >> ${CONFIG_PATH}`

and then
`jupyter notebook --allow-root -y --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --config=${CONFIG_PATH}`

However, if I then run the docker container via

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 <container-name>`

while it does start up jupyter and allows me to connect in my browser via `localhost:8888`, it won't accept the password I just set via its hash.

Strangely, it does work when I add the additional step of the SSL certificates (and go to https://localhost:8888). What's going on here?

PS: I know that having a password but no SSL is sketchy. I'm just testing it out step by step and wonder why it won't work without the SSL part.

Comment: The output of `passwd()` will be different each time because it is generating a random `salt` value to add to the password before going through the sha1 hash function. So that works as intended, as you thought. The password failing over HTTP while working over HTTPS does seem strange; I always run with a Let's Encrypt certificate, maybe someone with more Jupyter admin experience can explain what's going on / what is missing there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found two possible solutions, I tested both and both works.

jupyter core     : 4.6.3 
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3

**Set password**

"add option `-e PASSWORD=password` to set the environment variable. The set password is then the password for the jupyter login." [1] when `docker run` or

```
environment:
    - PASSWORD=password
```

when using Docker Compose. Then just enter password

**Set token**

"… There already exists an easy way of setting the token when starting one of the Jupyter notebook Docker containers: `-e JUPYTER_TOKEN="easy; it's already there"`. In fact, things are even easier if you `export JUPYTER_TOKEN='easy'` in the local environment, and then start the container with docker `run --rm -d --name democontainer -p 9999:8888 -e JUPYTER_TOKEN jupyter/base-notebook` (which is equivalent to `-e JUPYTER_TOKEN=$JUPYTER_TOKEN`). You can then autolaunch into the notebook with open `http://localhost:9999?token=${JUPYTER_TOKEN}`. H/t @minrk for that…" [2]

when using Docker Compose

```
environment:
    - JUPYTER_TOKEN=easy
```

then run just `http://localhost:9999?token=easy` or automate more ...

[1] [login password required to access jupyter notebook running in nvidia-docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202983/login-password-required-to-access-jupyter-notebook-running-in-nvidia-docker-cont)

[2] https://blog.ouseful.info/2019/02/05/on-not-faffing-around-with-jupyter-docker-container-auth-tokens/

Comment: For some reason, the first solution did not work for me. The second one works. Thanks!

Comment: I was using tensorflow-jupyter in docker then came across this problem. This commit https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/cae576317f93bee8be40cad560649e435f7998b8 told us the Password environment is removed in the latest version of jupyter

Answer (score 9):

Create a hashed password, using the ipython terminal

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
passwd()
```

It will promote you to enter the passwd twice, and create the hashed password,
and add following lines in the Docker file

```
RUN jupyter notebook --generate-config
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.password='sha1:***'">>/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Since I am the only person using the notebook, I just sticked to the root.

Answer (score 4):

it seems -e PASSWORD=easy not working anymore. I just tried to simply use

-e JUPYTER_TOKEN="easy"

it works as entering easy into password or token field on login page
Here is my command line to start the docker container as service:

```
    sudo docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped -p 8888:8888 -e JUPYTER_TOKEN="easy" jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31407970)

Comment: When scripting in Linux, the follow-up command `xdg-open http://localhost:8888/?token=easy` will pop open an authenticated browser window.