# Docker jupyter all-spark notebook : impossible to set the password

Tags: jupyter-notebook

From https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html#notebook-options I see we can start a container with a specified password with :

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/base-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password='sha1:74ba40f8a388:c913541b7ee99d15d5ed31d4226bf7838f83a50e'
```

I understand the password is here crypted and the sha1 value is [sha1:74ba40f8a388:c913541b7ee99d15d5ed31d4226bf7838f83a50e]

To crypt my own password according to https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html we can generate such a password with :

```
In [1]: from notebook.auth import passwd
In [2]: passwd()
```

I try it for the password "password" :

```
$ from notebook.auth import passwd
$ passwd("password")
'sha1:4259764db923:8f6a9501a8ba217c9f1616210991f412bafdcebd'
```

and then try to launch my container :

```
docker run -d -p 11000:8888 jupyter/base-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password='sha1:4259764db923:8f6a9501a8ba217c9f1616210991f412bafdcebd'
```

and... it works !?
yeah.. sometime you find the answer by explaining the question ;)

Comment: I use this solution to fix a static token, hopefully it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875436/jupyter-password-and-docker